# a different result (JAVA, MS ACCESS, SPRING)

Tags: java, sql, spring, ms-access, spring-mvc

I am maintaining an invoice sending system using JAVA(Spring 3.0, JDBCTemplate) with MS-ACCESS on Window platform. My problem is that when I retrive one of the table, the number of ResultSet is different. except for the table, everything is fine.

Here is my code and the table information.

(DAO)

```
    public List<QInv_RegularDto> getAdsForCustomer(String NO_Inv) {

    List<QInv_RegularDto> returnList = new ArrayList<QInv_RegularDto>();

    String sqlString = "SELECT ALL DT_Date"
    + "        , Day_Issued"
    + "        , NO_Inv"
    + "        , DS_Desc"
    + "        , AMT_Rate"
    + "        , Disc"
    + "        , AMT_Sub"
    + "        , AMT_GST"
    + "        , AMT_Tot"
    + "     FROM QInv_Regular "
    + "    WHERE NO_Inv = '0000039796';


    log.info("sss : " + sqlString);

    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sqlString);
    System.out.println("rows : " + rows.size());
    System.out.println("rows : " + rows);

    for (Map row : rows) {

        QInv_RegularDto ad = new QInv_RegularDto();

        ad.setdT_Date((String)row.get("DT_Date"));
        ad.setDay_Issued((String)row.get("Day_Issued"));
            ad.setnO_Inv((String)row.get("NO_Inv"));
        ad.setdS_Desc((String)row.get("DS_Desc"));
        ad.setaMT_Rate((BigDecimal)row.get("AMT_Rate"));
        ad.setDisc((Double)row.get("Disc"));
        ad.setaMT_Sub((BigDecimal)row.get("AMT_Sub"));
        ad.setaMT_GST((BigDecimal)row.get("AMT_GST"));
        ad.setaMT_Tot((BigDecimal)row.get("AMT_Tot"));

        returnList.add(ad);
    }


    return returnList;

}
```

When you see the code above, I print the size, query log and the result out and when I copy the query and run it on MS-ACCESS, I get 5 rows but in the code I only get 1 row. I tried to find a solution. I couldn't it. I have to get 5 rows.

please give me some advice.

Comment: I'd use a PreparedStatement and bind that query parameter.

Comment: I dont think so because when I put the query in my DAO  like below. the result is the same      SELECT  DT_Date, Day_Issued, NO_Inv, DS_Desc, AMT_Rate, Disc, AMT_Sub, AMT_GST, AMT_Tot FROM QInv_Regular WHERE NO_Inv = '0000039796'

Comment: whenever possible, always use `PreparedStatement`. Also note that MS-Access does not follow **real** SQL... what I do when running into dumb Access issues is build the query in Access, then copy that to your code, then fix it up so Java is happy.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Yes. we should use PreparedStatement. but the problem that I have is even though I changed my query, it does not work at all. the result is the same. I get 1 row. ~~....

Comment: Still wrong.  Why are you using Access instead of a real database?  No ODBC-JDBC bridge driver on 64 bit Windows.

Comment: //duffymo Thanks, duffymo. I have to use Access right now. As you said, I also want to use mysql, ms-sql and so on. but I have some reasons to use Access. Everything is fine but the above code only does not work. the environment is jdk 32bit and window 32bit and i use OJDBC with Access. Except for changing Access, I just want to know what the problem is.  Thank you, duffymo!

Answer (score 0):

found a solution. The problems was not about jdk, window problems and ODBC-JDBC. it is about MS-ACESS. I used other tables which I could get the data I wanted